# "Can't resolve types until ITypeIdentityResolutionService has started processing enqueued assemblies" after .NET 5 Winforms Migration

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

I have successfully migrated my .NET Framework 4.8 Windows Forms application to .NET 5. Everything builds and compiles, however, when trying to open the designer view for one of my forms, I get the following error:

[image]

The call stack is as follows:

```
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.WinForms.RemoteClient.Loader.RemoteCodeDomDesignerLoader.EnsureDocument(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.WinForms.RemoteClient.Loader.RemoteCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)
```

While I have hundreds of forms and can't 100% confirm this, this seems to be the only form with this issue. What could be causing this? Once again, no compiler issues and not a single error in the designer CS file.

**Edit:** I've discovered this only happens in a single project. If I create another form in this project, the same thing happens.

Comment: I'll note that other users have reported this to Microsoft (e.g., https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/windows-form-editor-doesnt-work-after-upgrade-to-1/1365687 ) without a successful resolution.

Comment: @Brian That's unfortunate, we're in crisis mode atm because of this. Weird to see that it's been months without a solution

Comment: Maybe see if JetBrains Rider will work as an alternative Forms editor? Mind you, that's more of an expensive way of giving up than an actual solution to your problem (hence why I'm not posting it as an answer).